# how to implement the geofencing using api response location without locationupdates and current location

Tags: geofencing, android-geofence

As I want to implement geofencing in my application without using current location and location updates. For School bus tracking system I need to implement.

Parent location is home location that is static not current location. Bus Location will be keep on changing when bus enter into the parent location ,notification need to trigger.How to do this functionality.I'm confused ,because geofencing will work based on current location.

Actually geofencing will work when current person enter into destination, notification will trigger, but my concept is reverse, when the bus enter into parent location ,notification need to trigger, can you please give some ideas.

```
public class SingleDestination extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE = 101;

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Button button2;
    private GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private boolean isMonitoring = false;

    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;

    private Marker currentLocationMarker;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";
    // Create a Intent send by the notification
    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg );
        return intent;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }


    }

    private void startLocationMonitor() {

        if (currentLocationMarker != null) {
            currentLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(new LatLng(13.0048683,77.548773));
        markerOptions.title("Current Location");
        currentLocationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
       /* Log.d(TAG, "start location monitor");
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(2000)
                .setFastestInterval(1000)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


                    Log.d("TT", "Location Change Lat Lng " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
*/
    }

    private void startGeofencing() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start geofencing monitoring call");
        pendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
        geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                .addGeofence(getGeofence())
                .build();

        if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Google API client not connected");
        } else {
            try {
                LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully Geofencing Connected");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to add Geofencing " + status.getStatus());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        isMonitoring = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @NonNull
    private Geofence getGeofence() {
 LatLng latLng = Constants.AREA_LANDMARKS.get(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID_STAN_UNI);

        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID_STAN_UNI)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setCircularRegion(13.0048683,77.548773, Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
                .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();


    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            return pendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceRegistrationService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private void stopGeoFencing() {
        pendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(googleApiClient, pendingIntent)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess())
                            Log.d(TAG, "Stop geofencing");
                        else
                            Log.d(TAG, "Not stop geofencing");
                    }
                });
        isMonitoring = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int response = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(SingleDestination.this);
        if (response != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Google Play Service Not Available");
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(SingleDestination.this, response, 1).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Google play service available");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.reconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manu_map_activity, menu);
        if (isMonitoring) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_start_monitor).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_stop_monitor).setVisible(true);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_start_monitor).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_stop_monitor).setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_start_monitor:
                startGeofencing();
                break;
            case R.id.action_stop_monitor:
                stopGeoFencing();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = Constants.AREA_LANDMARKS.get(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID_STAN_UNI);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.0048683,77.548773)).title("SK HOSPITAL"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.0048683,77.548773), 17f));

       // googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(13.0048683,77.548773))
                .radius(Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                .strokeWidth(4f));

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Api Client Connected");
        isMonitoring = true;
        startGeofencing();
        startLocationMonitor();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Connection Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        isMonitoring = false;
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection Failed:" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Note: Previosuly onconnected method I'm calling start Locationmontior to track current location, now current location is home location it wont change so i removed the location updates .But notification is not trigger, because we need to googlepaiclient to addgeofence method based on that it will work but my scenario is different .Please some one help me

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to have the lat-long of all the parents' houses on the school bus app and create GeoFences for all those Lat-Longs. Whenever a GeoFence is triggered, you can send an FCM to the parents app to let them know that the bus has reached their house.